# Edit files in my vagrant running on another device from my pc

Tags: ssh, vagrant

I am new to vagrant. I know i can connect to a vagrant running on another device. But can i work on the files and save the changes to my app running under that vagrant?

EDIT:

I mean can i use a editor like sublime text to connect to my applications files and work on it.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Please update and describe in detail what is your concern.

Comment: @techraf Updated. I basically want to work on my application's files hosted on another laptop from my pc.

Comment: It's even more unclear now, so just don't be surprised if it gets closed.

Comment: @techraf Idk if can make it more clear than this. My code files are hosted on my other device. And we are using vagrant for our development purposes. So i want to start the vagrant vm in my other device. Use my device (not the one running vagrant) to edit the files and preview changes.

Comment: as long as you can access the so-called other device (ftp, network drive ...) from your local device, you can edit those files and shared from the other device with the VM. what is the question ? Yes you can edit files if you are able to access them.